# pom.xml third party import issue

Tags: maven, maven-2, pom.xml, apache-servicemix

I am using ServiceMix 4, and am trying to modify the cxf-jaxrs demo. The following is my pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<!--

    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>examples</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>calendar-service</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<name>Calendar Api Demo :: CXF JAX-RS OSGI</name>
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>mandubian-mvn</id>
    <url>http://mandubian-mvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mandubian-mvn/repository</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-rc5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdata-client-1.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.41.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdata-calendar-2.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.41.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdata-core-1.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.41.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdata-base-1.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.41.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.specs.jsr311-api-1.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxb-api-${jaxb.api.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${servicemix.specs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Import-Package>
                            javax.wsdl,
                            javax.xml.bind,
                            javax.xml.bind.annotation,
                            javax.ws.rs,
                            META-INF.cxf,
                            META-INF.cxf.osgi,
                            org.apache.cxf.bus,
                            org.apache.cxf.bus.spring,
                            org.apache.cxf.bus.resource,
                            org.apache.cxf.resource,
                            org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring,
                            org.apache.cxf.binding,
                            org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils,
                            org.apache.cxf.transport.http_osgi,
                            org.springframework.beans.factory.config,
                            org.apache.commons.httpclient, 
                            org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods,
                            com.google.gdata.client.calendar;resolution:=optional,
                            com.google.gdata.data;resolution:=optional,
                            com.google.gdata.data.calendar;resolution:=optional,
                            com.google.gdata.data.extensions;resolution:=optional,
                            com.google.gdata.util;resolution:=optional
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Require-Bundle>org.apache.cxf.bundle</Require-Bundle>
                    <Export-Package>com.demo.*;</Export-Package>
                    <DynamicImport-Package>javax.ws.rs.*</DynamicImport-Package>
                 </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>edu.berkeley.api.client.Client</mainClass>
                <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Maven builds successfully, but when I try to deploy it on servicemix, I get:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gdata.data.calendar.CalendarEntry
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:814)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$100(ModuleImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1733)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 42 more

Am I missing a step? Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the ";resolution:=optional" from "com.google.gdata.data.calendar" so that OSGi can inform you when the required import is missing.

I had a look at the manifest of the JAR "gdata-calendar-2.0-1.41.5.jar" and it is lacking OSGi data. This means that you need to wrap the JAR as OSGi bundle. You can do this in the Karaf console with the wrap command:
osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:com.google.gdata/gdata-calendar-2.0/1.41.5